Cross-fitting seems to always reduce asymptotic variance for estimators converging slower than $\sqrt{n}$ - how can this be true?
Setup: Imagine the situation where you for a fixed value of your covariates have a regression estimator $\tilde{f}$ based on $n$ i.i.d. observations which is asymptotically normal with convergence rate $\alpha$ ($0 \leq \alpha \leq 1/2$), meaning
$$n^{\alpha}\{\tilde{f}-f\} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
in distribution, with $f$ being the true value. Examples include local linear regression at a point $x_0$ with bandwidth $h=n^{-1/5}$, which converges at rate $\sqrt{nh}=n^{2/5}$; so $\alpha=2/5$ in this case.
Instead of just inputting all $n$ observations into the regression method, suppose we do $K$-fold cross-fitting, where we randomly split the sample into $K$ groups and then average the results. Denote by $\tilde{f}_k$ the regression estimator based on only observations in fold $k$. Let
$$\tilde{f}^{CF} = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K \tilde{f}_k$$
be the cross-fitting estimator. Then
$$n^{\alpha}\{\tilde{f}^{CF} - f\} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(K^{\alpha}\mu,K^{2\alpha-1}\sigma^2).$$
Proof: Note first that
$$n^\alpha\{ \tilde{f}_k-f \} = K^\alpha \times (n/K)^\alpha\{ \tilde{f}_k-f \} \rightarrow K^\alpha \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) = \mathcal{N}(K^\alpha \mu , K^{2 \alpha} \sigma^2)$$
since only $n/K$ observations are used in $\tilde{f}_k$. Now
$$n^{\alpha}\{\tilde{f}^{CF} - f\} = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K} n^\alpha \{\tilde{f}_k - f\} \rightarrow \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K} \mathcal{N}(K^\alpha \mu , K^{2 \alpha} \sigma^2) = \mathcal{N}(K^\alpha \mu , K^{2 \alpha-1} \sigma^2)$$
in distribution, where the last equality uses the independence of $(\tilde{f}_k)_{k=1,\dots,K}$.
Question: This seems reasonable when $\mu \neq 0$ since increasing $K$ leads to a decrease in variance at the cost of an increase in bias - this is classic bias-variance tradeoff. But if $\mu=0$, it seems like you obtain an asymptotic variance reduction for free by increasing $K$. Can this really be true?
My only heuristic for why this might be okay is as follows: Local linear regression obtains the optimal convergence rate of $n^{2/5}$ (confer with Fan (1993) Section 4) but has $\mu \neq 0$. One can get rid of the bias by undersmoothing i.e. setting $h=n^{-1/5-\varepsilon}$ for a small $\varepsilon>0$. This leads to an estimator with $\alpha=2/5-\varepsilon/2$ but $\mu=0$. The reduction in convergence rate by $\varepsilon/2$ is asymptotically so bad that there is room to reduce the asymptotic variance arbitrarily much and still not break any optimality results.

In the OP's Proof we read

$$n^\alpha\{ \tilde{f}_k-f \} = K^\alpha \times (n/K)^\alpha\{\tilde{f}_k-f \} \rightarrow K^\alpha \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) =\mathcal{N}(K^\alpha \mu , K^{2 \alpha} \sigma^2)$$

This is wrong. It represents an assertion that the initial sample size (here, $n/K$) determines the variance of the limiting distribution. Namely the above expression implies (connecting the left-most to the right-most expression)
\begin{align*}
K= 2 \implies n^\alpha\{ \tilde{f}_k-f \} \to_d \mathcal{N}(2^\alpha \mu , 2^{2 \alpha} \sigma^2),\\
K=3 \implies n^\alpha\{ \tilde{f}_k-f \} \to_d \mathcal{N}(3^\alpha \mu , 3^{2 \alpha} \sigma^2)\\
etc
\end{align*}
Put another way, it asserts that splitting the original sample in a finite number of subsamples, still has consequences even when every subsample goes to "infinite" size.

Thanks for your input, but you are mistaken. The initial sample size has no effect, it is the relation between the number of observations used in the regression method (here n/K) and the number used for scaling the differences (here n) that plays a role. Take for example the average. Lets say you have n observations X_1,...,X_n but only use the first n/2, then the variance of the average is Var(X_1)/(n/2), so if you scale by n^(1/2) this scales the variance by n resulting in 2Var(X_1). Hence the variance in the asymptotic distribution becomes 2Var(X_1), not the usual Var(X_1).

@ProbabilityBoi I would like to understand this. In what sense "using the first $n/2$ observations" matters when we examine the limiting distribution that has $n\to \infty$? I am obviously missing something here. Also, in my post I did not look into what happens with $\tilde f^{CF}$ but what happens with the limiting distribution of the estimator from a single subsample $\tilde f_k$. Thanks for the discussion, I will think again about this and correct as appropriate.

Yes, I was also talking about a single subsample in my comment. Heuristically, the asymptotic distribution has to do with the speed of convergence. If you don't scale the differences by n^(1/2) for the average, then it converges to a one-point distribution at zero. You scale up by n^(1/2) since this gives you a non-degenerate distribution: scale by n^(1/2+epsilon) and it blows up, scale by n^(1/2-epsilon) and it converges to zero. Only using every other observation means to converge "half as fast", albeit with the same "order" i.e. exponent of n.
